# Содержит ли массив в mysql значение

Tags: sql, массивы, laravel, orm

Как найти запись в MySQL содержащей в колонке products ([1,55,2]) значение 55 ?

т.е. мне нужно чтобы whereIn отработал:
`->whereIn(55,'products')->get()`
понимаю, что с помощью whereIn это не сделать, но тогда как ?

MySQL, тип products - json. в модели указано

```
protected $casts = [
        'products' => 'array',
        ]
```

Comment: Опубликуйте структуру таблиц и тестовые данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `whereJsonContains`:

```
$casts = $db::table('casts')
    ->whereJsonContains('products', 55)
    ->get();
```

[Laravel query builder online](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql80/0c5188eda2b4ecc11acaf6f36d076c52/php/php8/1efc08143cd1c0d13c145fcaed1c54e9/)

Comment: Опубликуйте структуру таблиц и тестовые данные

Comment: Добавил онлайн тест